# T-SQL copy Logins, Users, roles, permissions etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, disaster-recovery, log-shipping

We have implemented log shipping as a database disaster recovery solution and want to know if there is a way I can use T-SQL to script all the logins, users, roles permissions etc to the master database on the secondary server so that the T-SQL can be sheduled to run as an SQL Job?

My aim is that in the event of a D/R situation we can simply restore the transaction logs for each database to the secondary server and not have to worry about orphaned users etc.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a login copy script here designed to copy logins to another server for disaster recovery purposes:

http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/transferring-logins-to-a-database-mirror

```
Use master;
Go

If Exists (Select 1 From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
            Where ROUTINE_NAME = 'dba_CopyLogins'
            And ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')
    Drop Procedure dbo.dba_CopyLogins
Go

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create Procedure dbo.dba_CopyLogins
    @PartnerServer sysname,
    @Debug bit = 0
As

Declare @MaxID int,
    @CurrID int,
    @SQL nvarchar(max),
    @LoginName sysname,
    @IsDisabled int,
    @Type char(1),
    @SID varbinary(85),
    @SIDString nvarchar(100),
    @PasswordHash varbinary(256),
    @PasswordHashString nvarchar(300),
    @RoleName sysname,
    @Machine sysname,
    @PermState nvarchar(60),
    @PermName sysname,
    @Class tinyint,
    @MajorID int,
    @ErrNumber int,
    @ErrSeverity int,
    @ErrState int,
    @ErrProcedure sysname,
    @ErrLine int,
    @ErrMsg nvarchar(2048)
Declare @Logins Table (LoginID int identity(1, 1) not null primary key,
                        [Name] sysname not null,
                        [SID] varbinary(85) not null,
                        IsDisabled int not null,
                        [Type] char(1) not null,
                        PasswordHash varbinary(256) null)
Declare @Roles Table (RoleID int identity(1, 1) not null primary key,
                    RoleName sysname not null,
                    LoginName sysname not null)
Declare @Perms Table (PermID int identity(1, 1) not null primary key,
                    LoginName sysname not null,
                    PermState nvarchar(60) not null,
                    PermName sysname not null,
                    Class tinyint not null,
                    ClassDesc nvarchar(60) not null,
                    MajorID int not null,
                    SubLoginName sysname null,
                    SubEndPointName sysname null)

Set NoCount On;

If CharIndex('\', @PartnerServer) > 0
  Begin
    Set @Machine = LEFT(@PartnerServer, CharIndex('\', @PartnerServer) - 1);
  End
Else
  Begin
    Set @Machine = @PartnerServer;
  End

-- Get all Windows logins from principal server
Set @SQL = 'Select P.name, P.sid, P.is_disabled, P.type, L.password_hash' + CHAR(10) +
        'From ' + QUOTENAME(@PartnerServer) + '.master.sys.server_principals P' + CHAR(10) +
        'Left Join ' + QUOTENAME(@PartnerServer) + '.master.sys.sql_logins L On L.principal_id = P.principal_id' + CHAR(10) +
        'Where P.type In (''U'', ''G'', ''S'')' + CHAR(10) +
        'And P.name <> ''sa''' + CHAR(10) +
        'And P.name Not Like ''##%''' + CHAR(10) +
        'And CharIndex(''' + @Machine + '\'', P.name) = 0;';

Insert Into @Logins (Name, SID, IsDisabled, Type, PasswordHash)
Exec sp_executesql @SQL;

-- Get all roles from principal server
Set @SQL = 'Select RoleP.name, LoginP.name' + CHAR(10) +
        'From ' + QUOTENAME(@PartnerServer) + '.master.sys.server_role_members RM' + CHAR(10) +
        'Inner Join ' + QUOTENAME(@PartnerServer) + '.master.sys.server_principals RoleP' +
        CHAR(10) + char(9) + 'On RoleP.principal_id = RM.role_principal_id' + CHAR(10) +
        'Inner Join ' + QUOTENAME(@PartnerServer) + '.master.sys.server_principals LoginP' +
        CHAR(10) + char(9) + 'On LoginP.principal_id = RM.member_principal_id' + CHAR(10) +
        'Where LoginP.type In (''U'', ''G'', ''S'')' + CHAR(10) +
        'And LoginP.name <> ''sa''' + CHAR(10) +
        'And LoginP.name Not Like ''##%''' + CHAR(10) +
        'And RoleP.type = ''R''' + CHAR(10) +
        'And CharIndex(''' + @Machine + '\'', LoginP.name) = 0;';

Insert Into @Roles (RoleName, LoginName)
Exec sp_executesql @SQL;

-- Get all explicitly granted permissions
Set @SQL = 'Select P.name Collate database_default,' + CHAR(10) +
        '   SP.state_desc, SP.permission_name, SP.class, SP.class_desc, SP.major_id,' + CHAR(10) +
        '   SubP.name Collate database_default,' + CHAR(10) +
        '   SubEP.name Collate database_default' + CHAR(10) +
        'From ' + QUOTENAME(@PartnerServer) + '.master.sys.server_principals P' + CHAR(10) +
        'Inner Join ' + QUOTENAME(@PartnerServer) + '.master.sys.server_permissions SP' + CHAR(10) +
        CHAR(9) + 'On SP.grantee_principal_id = P.principal_id' + CHAR(10) +
        'Left Join ' + QUOTENAME(@PartnerServer) + '.master.sys.server_principals SubP' + CHAR(10) +
        CHAR(9) + 'On SubP.principal_id = SP.major_id And SP.class = 101' + CHAR(10) +
        'Left Join ' + QUOTENAME(@PartnerServer) + '.master.sys.endpoints SubEP' + CHAR(10) +
        CHAR(9) + 'On SubEP.endpoint_id = SP.major_id And SP.class = 105' + CHAR(10) +
        'Where P.type In (''U'', ''G'', ''S'')' + CHAR(10) +
        'And P.name <> ''sa''' + CHAR(10) +
        'And P.name Not Like ''##%''' + CHAR(10) +
        'And CharIndex(''' + @Machine + '\'', P.name) = 0;'

Insert Into @Perms (LoginName, PermState, PermName, Class, ClassDesc, MajorID, SubLoginName, SubEndPointName)
Exec sp_executesql @SQL;

Select @MaxID = Max(LoginID), @CurrID = 1
From @Logins;

While @CurrID <= @MaxID
  Begin
    Select @LoginName = Name,
        @IsDisabled = IsDisabled,
        @Type = [Type],
        @SID = [SID],
        @PasswordHash = PasswordHash
    From @Logins
    Where LoginID = @CurrID;

    If Not Exists (Select 1 From sys.server_principals
                Where name = @LoginName)
      Begin
        Set @SQL = 'Create Login ' + quotename(@LoginName)
        If @Type In ('U', 'G')
          Begin
            Set @SQL = @SQL + ' From Windows;'
          End
        Else
          Begin
            Set @PasswordHashString = '0x' +
                Cast('' As XML).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@PasswordHash"))', 'nvarchar(300)');

            Set @SQL = @SQL + ' With Password = ' + @PasswordHashString + ' HASHED, ';

            Set @SIDString = '0x' +
                Cast('' As XML).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@SID"))', 'nvarchar(100)');
            Set @SQL = @SQL + 'SID = ' + @SIDString + ';';
          End

        If @Debug = 0
          Begin
            Begin Try
                Exec sp_executesql @SQL;
            End Try
            Begin Catch
                Set @ErrNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();
                Set @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
                Set @ErrState = ERROR_STATE();
                Set @ErrProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
                Set @ErrLine = ERROR_LINE();
                Set @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE();
                RaisError(@ErrMsg, 1, 1);
            End Catch
          End
        Else
          Begin
            Print @SQL;
          End

        If @IsDisabled = 1
          Begin
            Set @SQL = 'Alter Login ' + quotename(@LoginName) + ' Disable;'
            If @Debug = 0
              Begin
                Begin Try
                    Exec sp_executesql @SQL;
                End Try
                Begin Catch
                    Set @ErrNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();
                    Set @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
                    Set @ErrState = ERROR_STATE();
                    Set @ErrProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
                    Set @ErrLine = ERROR_LINE();
                    Set @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE();
                    RaisError(@ErrMsg, 1, 1);
                End Catch
              End
            Else
              Begin
                Print @SQL;
              End
          End
        End
    Set @CurrID = @CurrID + 1;
  End

Select @MaxID = Max(RoleID), @CurrID = 1
From @Roles;

While @CurrID <= @MaxID
  Begin
    Select @LoginName = LoginName,
        @RoleName = RoleName
    From @Roles
    Where RoleID = @CurrID;

    If Not Exists (Select 1 From sys.server_role_members RM
                Inner Join sys.server_principals RoleP
                    On RoleP.principal_id = RM.role_principal_id
                Inner Join sys.server_principals LoginP
                    On LoginP.principal_id = RM.member_principal_id
                Where LoginP.type In ('U', 'G', 'S')
                And RoleP.type = 'R'
                And RoleP.name = @RoleName
                And LoginP.name = @LoginName)
      Begin
        If @Debug = 0
          Begin
            Exec sp_addsrvrolemember @rolename = @RoleName,
                            @loginame = @LoginName;
          End
        Else
          Begin
            Print 'Exec sp_addsrvrolemember @rolename = ''' + @RoleName + ''',';
            Print '     @loginame = ''' + @LoginName + ''';';
          End
      End

    Set @CurrID = @CurrID + 1;
  End

Select @MaxID = Max(PermID), @CurrID = 1
From @Perms;

While @CurrID <= @MaxID
  Begin
    Select @PermState = PermState,
        @PermName = PermName,
        @Class = Class,
        @LoginName = LoginName,
        @MajorID = MajorID,
        @SQL = PermState + space(1) + PermName + SPACE(1) +
            Case Class When 101 Then 'On Login::' + QUOTENAME(SubLoginName)
                    When 105 Then 'On ' + ClassDesc + '::' + QUOTENAME(SubEndPointName)
                    Else '' End +
            ' To ' + QUOTENAME(LoginName) + ';'
    From @Perms
    Where PermID = @CurrID;

    If Not Exists (Select 1 From sys.server_principals P
                Inner Join sys.server_permissions SP On SP.grantee_principal_id = P.principal_id
                Where SP.state_desc = @PermState
                And SP.permission_name = @PermName
                And SP.class = @Class
                And P.name = @LoginName
                And SP.major_id = @MajorID)
      Begin
        If @Debug = 0
          Begin
            Begin Try
                Exec sp_executesql @SQL;
            End Try
            Begin Catch
                Set @ErrNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();
                Set @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
                Set @ErrState = ERROR_STATE();
                Set @ErrProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
                Set @ErrLine = ERROR_LINE();
                Set @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE();
                RaisError(@ErrMsg, 1, 1);
            End Catch
          End
        Else
          Begin
            Print @SQL;
          End
      End

    Set @CurrID = @CurrID + 1;
  End

Set NoCount Off;
```

Comment: I'm getting errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW'.
Msg 50000, Level 1, State 1